# client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23) - From Android

Tags: android, apache, httpurlconnection, hostname

I am seeing this in Apache Logs. Basically the request is going from Android Emulator using `HTTPUrlConnection`. Here is my code.

```
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);  
            Log.d(params[0],"UR");  


            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(toencode, Base64.DEFAULT));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.domain.com");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC; en-US; rv:1.3.1)");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setConnectTimeout (30000) ; 
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            conn.setDoInput(true); 
            conn.connect();
            String data = conn.getInputStream().toString();
            return data;
```

I am sending the user-agent header to make sure the server is not filtering non-recognizable user agents. I captured the traffic using Wireshark. The request seems to be okay. Not sure what else to look for. Spending hours on this without luck.

```
 GET Authenticate/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
 Host: www.domain.com\r\n
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC; en-US; rv:1.3.1)\r\n
 Accept-Charset: UTF-8\r\n
 Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
 Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n
 \r\n
```

Response from Server:

```
 Request Version: HTTP/1.1
 Status Code: 400
 Response Phrase: Bad Request


 <h1>Bad Request</h1>\n
 <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n
```

and in the apache logs:

```
 client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23)
```

At this point I feel like I need to go back to HttpClient and try it. I thought I should use `HttpUrlConnection` because google recommends it. But I am having no luck with `HttpURLConnection`.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator was not sending Host header properly. So I was receiving Bad Request from server.
Wireshark helped me resolve this issue.